# winRT RichEditBox: change foreground on limited range of characters

Tags: text, microsoft-metro, format, winrt-xaml

I have tried several things to update the character format of my RichEditBox but I haven't been able to change it. Here is what I tried until now:

I have a given:

```
private RichEditBox _highlitedTextControlReference;
```

Attempt:

```
this._highlitedTextControlReference.Document.GetRange(0, 2).CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Orange;
```

Another attempt:

```
var format = _highlitedTextControlReference.Document.GetDefaultCharacterFormat();
format.ForegroundColor = Colors.Orange;
_highlitedTextControlReference.Document.SetDefaultCharacterFormat(format);
_highlitedTextControlReference.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();
_highlitedTextControlReference.Document.Selection.TypeText("blah");
```

Another attempt:

```
_highlitedTextControlReference.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Orange;
_highlitedTextControlReference.Document.Selection.TypeText("blah");
```

I tried to change a boolean I found:

```
_highlitedTextControlReference.IsColorFontEnabled = true;
```

But all these things didn't have any effect...

Am I missing somthing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this highlighting in response to TextChanged event ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Not in every cases. Actually I tried multiple events for my bench. As far as I can remember, Loaded was the one I used the most.
Is there something related to the event or the life cycle I would have missed?

Comment: Recently I tried to do that. I found no issue. See http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Syntax-Editor-for-WinRT-c556d223

Comment: Thanks for the link Adnan, I'll check what's going in my case with your code. I'll keep you informed!